# Reading property file

Tags: java, xml, properties-file

I have an application.properties file where I have listed the "env.baseurl".

I have another file "requestcall.xml" where this URL from properties file needs to be passed within the block for API (webservice).

There is a tag of  in which I want to pass the URL. Could anyone please guide me, thanks in advance.

Comment: can you give the code of properties file and what you have tried so far.

Comment: Provide some more details like is it a simple java application or you are using any framework like spring?

Answer (score 0):

Try this to read application properties xml using spring

```
@Value("${env.baseurl}")
private String envBaseURL;
```

Answer (score 0):

To load these properties files in an application, we use `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` .
You need to configure your xml file to read the `.propertiles` file.

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurerService" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
   <property name="locations">
       <list>
           <value>classpath:application.properties</value>
       </list>
   </property>
</bean>
```

Now you need to read **env.baseurl** as per your requirement:

```
<bean class="your class">
  <property name="baseurl"><value>${env.baseurl}</value></property>
</bean>
```

I will advice to look into the beautiful article over [Dzone](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-be-careful-when-using-propertyplaceholderconfigurer), it will clear your doubts as certain.

Comment: Not sure if the question was referring spring or DI context :-)